Mecanum wheels not moving as per expectation
I am  working on a robot with 4 mecanum wheels. I am using the following mecanum wheel controller "https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/pull/512". The robot is working fine in rviz, means the rotation of wheel is perfect for all types of movement that a mecanum wheel is expected to have. But in gazebo, few movements are not being performed. I am able to move it forward, backward, rotate but the robot is not gliding sideways and diagonally. The wheels are moving fine in gazebo as well but the robot is not moving in the desired direction for few movements (gliding sideways and diagonally). I am using a .stl mesh for the wheels.
I suspect the following URDF tag values to be responsible for this:

Collision
Inertial

Below is the list of different cases I have tested out. I have used mesh for visual tag through out all case:

CASE_1:

Collision Tag: Used a cylinder shape.
Inertia: Inertia for a cylinder at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors"
Observation: The robot is moving as if there are many pit(small hole) in the ground. Feels like an off-road drive. The robot is bouncing as it moves. The Tyer(Wheel) sink into the ground many times.
I have gone through the following posts(many others) and none of these seems to help:

https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16855/object-falls-off-through-ground-plane-instead-of-resting-on-it-when-spawned-in-gazebo/
https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27418/simulation-meshes-falling-through-floor/
Gazebo urdf model falls through the ground


Using a spherical shape in collision tag instead of a cylinder solves this issue.


CASE_2:

Collision Tag: Used a sphere shape.
Inertia: Inertia for a sphere at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors".
Observation: Tier does not sink into ground but some moves(side glide and diagonal movement) are not being performed event though the tires are rotating is the desired direction.


CASE_3:

Collision: Using the same Mesh as used in visual tag.
Inertia: Inertia for a cylinder at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#List_of_3D_inertia_tensors".
Observation: Same as case 2 but a bit slow movements.



QUESTIONS:

Does having different shapes for visual and collision tag has any influence over the movement(like using mecanum mesh for visual tag and cylinder shape for collision tag?

Does inertial values also has influence on movements (like robot not gliding sideways and diagonally)? If yes, how can I compute inertial values for a complicated mesh(mecanum wheel in my case)? I used CheckGeometry feature of FreeCAD (https://wiki.freecad.org/Part_CheckGeometry) to find out the inertial values but it is showing 1.0 for xx, yy, zz(0 for others) which does not seems correct.

Do I need to have a specific distance/angle between the wheels for the mecanum wheels to work or any rectangular shape would work? (in my case the robot chassi is 600cm X 600cm X 2cm RECTANGLE).


NOTE: Keeping the robot fixed in rviz, the wheel movements are perfect. Also forward, backward and turning movements are working fine in GAZEBO. The issue is only with sliding sideways and diagonally.

Have added the URDF below.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro" />
    
    <!-- Colors -->
    <material name="purple">
        <color rgba="0.5 0 0.5 1"/>
    </material>    
    
    <material name="white">
        <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
    </material>    
    
                
    <!-- Chassis Properties -->
    <xacro:property name="chassis_width" value="0.6"/>       <!-- 6 meter = 600 cm -->
    <xacro:property name="chassis_height" value="0.6"/>      <!-- 6 meter = 600 cm -->
    <xacro:property name="chassis_depth" value="0.02"/>      <!-- 0.02meter = 2 cm -->
    <xacro:property name="chassis_mass" value="1"/>          <!-- 1 kg -->
    
    <!-- Wheel Properties -->
    <xacro:property name="wheel_radius" value="0.04"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_width" value="0.04"/>
    <xacro:property name="wheel_mass" value="0.01"/>
    
    <!-- Wheel Macro -->
    <xacro:macro name="wheel_macro" params="wheel_name wheel_color mu1 mu2 type">    <!-- mu max_val = 1 (max friction) min_val = 0(min friction) -->
        <link name="${wheel_name}">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
               <!-- <cylinder length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}" /> -->
               <mesh filename="/home/temp_wheel/Type${type}.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>              
                </geometry>
                <material name="white"/>
            </visual>        
            
            <collision>
                <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <sphere radius="${wheel_radius}" />
                <!-- <mesh filename="/home/temp_wheel/Type${type}.obj" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/> -->
                    <!-- <cylinder length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}" /> -->
                </geometry>
            </collision>
            
            <!-- FOR SPHERE -->
            <!--
             <xacro:macro name="inertial_sphere" params="mass radius *origin">
                <inertial>
                    <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
                    <mass value="${mass}" />
                <inertia ixx="${(2/5) * mass * (radius*radius)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                            iyy="${(2/5) * mass * (radius*radius)}" iyz="0.0"
                        izz="${(2/5) * mass * (radius*radius)}" />
                </inertial>
            </xacro:macro>  
            -->
           
            <!-- TESTING different values -->            
            <inertial>
                <mass value="${wheel_mass}" />
                <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                        iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0"
                        izz="0.0001" />
            </inertial>
            
            
            <!-- FOR CYLINDER -->
            <!--
            <xacro:macro name="inertial_cylinder" params="mass length radius *origin">
                <inertial>
                    <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
                    <mass value="${mass}" />
                <inertia ixx="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
                            iyy="${(1/12) * mass * (3*radius*radius + length*length)}" iyz="0.0"
                        izz="${(1/2) * mass * (radius*radius)}" />
                </inertial>
            </xacro:macro>
            -->    
            
        </link>
        
        <gazebo reference="${wheel_name}">
        <material>${wheel_color}</material>
            
            <mu1 value="${mu1}"/>
        <mu2 value="${mu2}"/>    
        </gazebo>
            
    </xacro:macro>
           
               
    <!-- BASE LINK -->
    <link name="base_link">
    </link>
    
    <!-- Chassis Link -->
    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="chassis_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.06"/>    <!-- xyz = 0, 0, height_to_raise + chassis_depth/2 -->
    </joint>
    
    <link name="chassis_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${chassis_width} ${chassis_height} ${chassis_depth}"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="purple"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="${chassis_width} ${chassis_height} ${chassis_depth}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <xacro:inertial_box mass="${chassis_mass}" x="${chassis_width}" y="${chassis_height}" z="${chassis_depth}"> 
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_box>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="chassis_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Purple</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    
    <!-- Front Left Wheel -->    
    <!-- <joint name="front_left_joint" type="continuous"> -->
    <joint name="dummy_left_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link" />
        <child link="front_left_link" />
        <origin xyz="0.3 0.32 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <xacro:wheel_macro wheel_name="front_left_link" wheel_color="Gazebo/Green" mu1="1.0" mu2="1.0" type="2"/>
    
    
    <!-- Front Right Wheel -->
    <!-- <joint name="front_right_joint" type="continuous"> -->
    <joint name="dummy_right_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link" />
        <child link="front_right_link" />
        <origin xyz="0.3 -0.32 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <xacro:wheel_macro wheel_name="front_right_link" wheel_color="Gazebo/Green" mu1="1.0" mu2="1.0" type="1"/>
    
    <!-- Rear Left Wheel -->
    <!-- <joint name="rear_left_joint" type="continuous"> -->
    <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link" />
        <child link="rear_left_link" />
        <origin xyz="-0.3 0.32 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <xacro:wheel_macro wheel_name="rear_left_link" wheel_color="Gazebo/Yellow" mu1="1.0" mu2="1.0" type="1"/>
    
    <!-- Rear Right Wheel -->
    <!-- <joint name="rear_right_joint" type="continuous"> -->
    <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="chassis_link" />
        <child link="rear_right_link" />
        <origin xyz="-0.3 -0.32 0" rpy="0 0 ${pi/2}" />    
        <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>    
        <!-- 0.3 (half chassis width) + 0.01 (half tyer width) + 0.01 (safety margin). -->
        
    </joint>
    
    <xacro:wheel_macro wheel_name="rear_right_link" wheel_color="Gazebo/Yellow" mu1="1.0" mu2="1.0" type="2"/>
    
</robot>

Let me know if any other information is required.
EDIT:
Link to .stl wheel files: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/9exnedj966hyyily3bflc/AI7BvLR9tjqW7-oxawawFtc?rlkey=7fv9por3rnoodmvlolpb16s9q&st=wnuc8gwx&dl=0
Thanks

Welcome to Robotics, Pratham. Are you expecting that Gazebo is going to do the physics work for you, which will be what gets the mecanum wheels to work as expected? The lateral/diagonal movement happens because the little pinions on the mecanum wheel can rotate, but it looks like you are providing physics definitions that treat the wheels as solid objects. I don't think you'll get the movement you want until you enable some lateral motion in the wheel.

@Chuck You mean the pinons are fixed according to your observation? How do I find out if its fixed? I have attached the link to the ".stl" wheel mesh files by updating the question at the end.
I thought it is because of using solid shapes(cylinder and sphere) in "collision" tag and  I replace the collision tag content with the same mesh as visual tag but the movements are the same.

You can find it out from your URDF - in the wheel macro, you import the whole mecanum assembly (wheel + pinions) as one single object. To the URDF, it says that this is one fixed object, hence it makes sense that it cannot translate in the Y direction. What you can try doing is model separately one of such wheels, where you add each pinion as a continuous joint along the wheel, and perform experiments to see if you can move the wheel assembly laterally in gazebo - this should normally be taken care of the Physics solver if I'm not wrong.

@ssarkar It makes sense but wouldn't it be too difficult to attach each pinion precisely on the desired location forming a circle? I think there would be a better approach.

@Chuck ok. I will try this. You can post this as answer and I will mark it if it works out. Thanks.

You should have a frame for each pinion. If you see the frames then they probably don't exist. If you're not defining the frames then they don't exist. You ask

wouldn't it be too difficult to attach each pinion precisely on the desired location forming a circle?

But these get fabricated in real life, right? Define one joint for one pinion, then copy/paste on (what appears to be) 30 degree increments - this is a perfect task for xacro. I would split the geometry for the pinions off from the geometry for the wheel, then you can visually check that it's correct.
